# Ajax Undefined index

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Olá, alguém por obséquio poderia me ajudar? Já fui em vários sites tentando resolver esse problema.

O código js funciona perfeitamente, e o `$("#links").load( "buscas.php" );` chega a carregar, mas o código PHP sempre da o erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: buscas in.

A meu ver o js não está conseguindo enviar os dados para o buscas.php, mas o motivo, não faço a menor ideia.

Não sei mais o que fazer, até diminui o código e deixei esse bobinho aqui em baixo e mesmo assim obtive o mesmo erro.

Código Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){

        botao = $(this).html();

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"HTML",
            url:"buscas.php",
            data: {tipo: botao},
            success: function(data){
            $("#links").load( "buscas.php" );

            }
        }); 

    });

});
```

Código PHP (buscas.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['tipo'])){

    $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];

    echo "Botao ".$tipo." precionado";

}
else{
    echo "Variavel nao definida";
}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
   <script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js">

   </script> <script src="js/busca.js"> </script> 

   <title>Links</title> 

  </head> 

   <body>
 <button id='botao'>botao1</button><br>
 <button id='botao'>botao2</button><br>

      <div id="linksPainel">

         <div id="links"> 

         </div> 

      </div>

   </body> 

</html>
```

@WilliamNovak Esse foi o único código que não mostrei. Sorry, achei que não teria importancia.

---

```
<?php 
    require "dbPDO.php";

    if(isset($_POST['tipo'])){

        $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];

        $busca = $conect->prepare("SELECT * FROM link WHERE tipo = '".$tipo."' ORDER BY id DESC ");
        $busca->execute();

        echo "<h2>$tipo</h2>";
        while ($row = $busca->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            # code...
            $nome = $row['nome'];
            $link = $row['link'];
            echo "<a href='$link' target='_blank'>$nome</a><br>";

        }
    }else{
        echo "Variavel nao definida";
    }

?>
```

Tá aí!

Comment: Posta o resto do código, por que _Notice: Undefined index: buscas in._ significa que você em algum momento tá chamando uma variável ou índice em um _array_ que não existe e esse isso tá interferindo no resultado que espera.

Comment: Esse é todo o código, o Notice: Undefined index: buscas in acontece se eu remover o if(isset($_POST['tipo'])) que verifica se uma variável foi definida. Se eu deixar, ele entra no else "echo "Variavel nao definida";" Ou seja a variável realmente não está sedo definida, mas não encontro o problema. Eu deixei esse código simples para tentar achar o problema, mas não consegui.

Answer (score 1):

Seu javascript está fazendo 2 posts. É pra fazer isso mesmo? Sem mencionar que no segundo ele não está enviando nada para `buscas.php` (onde deve ocorrer o erro).
Se a ideia é receber o resultado de `buscas.php` de acordo com os parâmetros recebidos, tente algo como

```
$.post("buscas.php", {tipo: botao}, function(data){
    //Resultado após o post
});
```

Se quiser utilizar GET:

```
$.get("buscas.php", {tipo: botao}, function(data){
    //Resultado após o get
});
```

Se quiser usar o método load:

```
$("#links").load( "buscas.php", {tipo: botao} );
```